# Shiny and DT: how to reset an output that depends on calculations over inputs?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, reactive

I really had trouble finding a title for this question, hope it helps.

I have a fairly complex app for which I'm having trouble resetting an output after an `actionButton` ("Confirm" on this example) triggers the re-evaluation of a `reactiveValues` number that feeds a reactive table.

This causes that the `selected` table only renders once and no matter how many times the table that feeds it changes, it keeps showing the same result as the first time it was rendered.

It will be easy for you to see what I mean from this example. Believe me, it is the minimax from the one I'm coming from:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
 

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table"),
  actionButton("checkvalues", "Check")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  primedata <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  primedata$data <- as.numeric(Sys.time()) %% 10000 
  
  tabledata <- reactive({
    
    data <- data.frame(rep(primedata$data, 5))
    for (i in 1:5) {
      data$V1[i] <- as.character(selectInput(paste0("sel", i), "",
                                             choices = c("None selected" = 0,
                                                          "Icecream", "Donut"), 
                                                          selected = 0, width = "120px"))
  }
    return(data)
    })
  
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable( #Generar tabla
    
    tabledata(), filter = 'top', escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
            var $this = $(this.node());
            $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
            $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
          });
          Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
          Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    
  )
  
  # helper function for reading inputs in DT
  shinyValue = function(id, len) { 
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) { 
      value = input[[paste0(id, i)]] 
      if (is.null(value)) NA else value 
    })) 
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$checkvalues, {
    
    datos <- tabledata()
    
      selected <- cbind(datos, data.frame(N = shinyValue("sel", nrow(datos)))) 
      selected <- selected %>% group_by(N) %>% summarise("see" = n())
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = HTML('<h3 style="text-align:center;">Problem: this table will keep showing the same results as the first one presented</h3>'),
      renderDT(datatable(selected, options = list(dom = 't', ordering = F))),
      footer = actionButton("Confirm", "Confirm")))
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Confirm, {
    
     primedata$data <- as.numeric(Sys.time()) %% 10000
      
     removeModal() 

    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question (I have not tried your code) but to use `shinyjs` you must include `useShinyjs()` in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I removed the elements of ~shinyjs since those are not being incidental to the problem.

Comment: So you want to get a table with the selections ? Right ?

Comment: Yes, using the same dependencies structure wherever possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change `primedata$data` (by clicking on the Confirm button) this re-renders the table, and you have to unbind before:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(
    HTML(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbindDT', function(id) {
        var $table = $('#'+id).find('table');
        if($table.length > 0){
          Shiny.unbindAll($table.DataTable().table().node());
        }
      })")
  )),
  DTOutput("table"),
  actionButton("checkvalues", "Check")
)


  observeEvent(input$Confirm, {
    
    session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "table")
    
    primedata$data <- as.numeric(Sys.time()) %% 10000
    
    removeModal() 
    
  })
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution, but maybe the "table" name for the output in my example is not the best in this case (the datatable output in my app has another name). I dont know javascript, so... are all of the `table`s on the HTML script on your answer reffering to the output or should I keep any of them?

Comment: @DavidJorquera `"table"` in `session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "table")` refers to the output id (`output$table <- renderDT(......)`).

Comment: ...and the script stays the same, got it... it worked on the example and on my app. THANK YOU!